# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object' TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have this array.map function:

```
{props.help.map((e, i) => {
return <a key={i}>{e.name}</a>
})}
```

{e} object have 'name' and 'href' keys

i got "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'" (typescript)

I am beginner in typescript.

Comment: Can you show a sample props.help array of objects?  Also, if this is in typescript, then you need to define the types of your inputs to the map function.  e.g., "(e:any, i:number)=> {..." or something of the sort.

Comment: here is props interface: 

interface IData {
 help: object[]
}

if i use this:

interface HelpObject {
name: string
href: string
}
i got Argument of type '(e: HelpObject, i: number) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface for a `Help` object, and use it in the definition of your props:

```
interface Help {
  name: string;
  // other properties
}

interface Props {
  help: Help[];
}
```

And then use `Props` when defining the component:

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either cast the object to type `any` or the best practice is to add a type definition.

```
interface ExampleObject {
    name: string;
}
```

```
{
  props.help.map((e: ExampleObject, i) => {
    return <a key={i}>{e.name}</a>
  })
}
```